# Rows Containing More Than One Information (pairwise survey data analysis)

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, data-science, data-analysis

I have a dataframe like this below :

```
d={'strategy_left': ['1  1  4  2  2  4  3  2  1  6  5  3  1  1  1  4  3  2  5  2  3',
        '3  3  1  4  5  2  4  1  1  3  6  4  1  2  2  2  5  2  1  1  3',
        '1  1  3  2  3  2  2  3  4  4  1  6  5  4  1  2  5  2  1  3  1',
        '3  2  2  3  4  6  1  5  4  1  3  5  2  1  3  1  1  2  4  1  2'], 
'strategy_right': ['7  4  5  7  3  6  6  4  6  7  6  7  2  3  5  7  5  5  7  6  4',
        '5  4  4  7  7  5  5  6  5  6  7  6  7  7  6  3  6  4  2  3  7',
        '6  7  6  7  7  5  3  5  7  6  5  7  7  5  2  6  6  4  3  4  4',
        '7  4  3  4  6  7  3  6  5  6  6  7  5  7  5  5  4  6  7  2  7'], 
'decision_Left1_Right2_Tie0': ['1  1  2  1  2  2  2  1  2  1  1  2  1  1  2  2  2  2  1  2  1', 
             '1  1  1  2  1  2  2  0  2  1  1  2  1  0  2  2  0  1  1  2  2',
             '2  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  2  1  1  2  2  2  2  1  2  1  1',
             '1  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2  2  2  1  2  2  1  2  1  2  2  2  1'], 
'decision_difficulty':['1  1  4  2  2  4  3  2  1  6  5  3  1  1  1  4  3  2  5  2  3', 
                      '1  1  4  2  2  4  3  2  1  6  5  3  1  1  1  4  3  2  5  2  3', 
                      '1  1  4  2  2  4  3  2  1  6  5  3  1  1  1  4  3  2  5  2  3', 
                      '1  1  4  2  2  4  3  2  1  6  5  3  1  1  1  4  3  2  5  2  3']}
```

So each row is a string containing 21 numbers. 'decision' is my target column. It shows the winner of the strategies shown in the 'strategy_right' or 'strategy_left' columns.

Meaning in a pairwise comparison model strategy 1 was shown on the left side of the screen and strategy 7 was shown on the right side of the screen and participant choose '1' (strategy shown on the left side of the screen which is strategy 1.)

I want to know how many times each strategy has been choosen over the entire dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
temp = df['DecisionDifficulty'].str.split(' ').values
```

You will then need to iterate over these and map them back to your question ID.

You can also put this in a function and apply it over rows to make life easier.

I think the line above is what you "need" to get moving.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help me much. when I run above code I get an array looks like this : array([list(['1', '', '1', '', '4', '', '2', '', '2', '', '4', '', '3', '', '2', '', '1', '', '6', '', '5', '', '3', '', '1', '', '1', '', '1', '', '4', '', '3', '', '2', '', '5', '', '2', '', '3'], ........). I edited the question entirely, so people can try themselves.